# how to do a simple loop in ARM inline Assembly with NDK?

Tags: c, loops, assembly, android-ndk, arm

I'm trying to do a simple loop in ARM Assembly, but every time i run it crashes
this is the log:

> 01-13 15:34:21.277: A/libc(27296): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 27312 (Thread-2932)

and here is my code what am i doing wrong?

```
 void foo(int *pIn, int *pOut) {
    //pIn contains the number of iterations the loop will have
    asm volatile(
        "ldr r3, %[in];"
        "ldr r4, %[out];"
        "ldr r5, [r3];"

        "loop:; "
        //here would go the code inside the loop perhaps put something in output, in this case just do nothing
        "subs r5, r5, #1;"
        "bne loop"

        :[out] "=m" (pOut)
        :[in] "m" (pIn)
        :"r3","r4","r5","memory" 
    );
}
```

and in Android.mk file i put the 32bit directive

> LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm

any ideas why it is crashing?
the crash only occurs when i put the loop, before this i tried moving things around and it worked perfectly fine giving output values as i expected.

Comment: Shouldn't `r5` be in your clobber list?

Comment: You should also add `"cc"` to the clobber list to let GCC know the condition flags are modified.

Comment: Do you put `ldr r5,[r3]` **without** the loop?  You do a 2nd pointer indirection.  So `*pIn` should be `int **pIn`...  The error message shows a NULL pointer access.  Maybe you want `mov r5,r3`?

Comment: Also, I think the `=m` specifier gets the address of the variable.  I think you just want `=r` as a specifier.  Basically, `int foo; asm(... : "=r" (&foo)); asm(... : "=m" (foo));` are equivalent with the 2nd giving the compiler a clue that `foo` changed.  I think you might get an extra address taken with an `=m` specifier.  Running `objdump -S foo.o` on the compiler output to get an assembler listing would help everyone.

Comment: @MichaelBurr you are right it was a clobber list issue

Comment: @artlessnoise you are also right!

Comment: why are you doing this with inline assembly?  just write assembly for this function...then if you really really feel the need then deal with compiler issues to inline that code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is solved, adding "r5" and "cc" to my clobber list made it work.
here is the working code:

```
void foo(int *pIn, int *pOut) {
     //pIn contains the number of iterations the loop will have
     asm volatile(
         "ldr r3, %[in];"
         "ldr r4, %[out];"
         "ldr r5, [r3];"

         "loop:; "
         //here would go the code inside the loop perhaps put something in output, in this case just do nothing
         "subs r5, r5, #1;"
         "bne loop"

         :[out] "=m" (pOut)
         :[in] "m" (pIn)
         :"r3","r4","r5","cc","memory" 
     );
 }
```